# Finding a common basket of products in SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have this table:

```
CREATE TABLE my_table (
    the_id varchar(5) NOT NULL, 
    the_date timestamp NOT NULL,
    the_city varchar(5) NOT NULL,
    the_product varchar(1) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO my_table
VALUES ('VIS01', '2019-05-02 09:00:00','LISBO','A'), 
       ('VIS02', '2019-05-04 12:00:00','EVORA','A'), 
       ('VIS03', '2019-05-05 18:00:00','LISBO','B'), 
       ('VIS04', '2019-05-06 18:30:00','PORTO','B'), 
       ('VIS05', '2019-05-15 12:00:00','PORTO','C'), 
       ('VIS06', '2019-06-30 18:00:00','EVORA','C'),
       ('VIS07', '2019-06-30 18:00:00','PORTO','A'),
       ('VIS08', '2019-06-30 18:00:00','EVORA','B'),
       ('VIS09', '2019-06-30 18:00:00','LISBO','B');
```

And I want to find all `the_product` that are common for the cities. In this case, products A and B are common to all the three cities, so we can create a basket of common products, and it's frequency:

The result should be:

```
the_product    freq
A              3
B              4
```

Please, any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One approach, using a distinct count select to find the total number of all cities:

```sql
SELECT the_product, COUNT(*) AS freq
FROM my_table
GROUP BY the_product
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT the_city) = (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT the_city) FROM my_table);
```

### Demo

In plain English, the above query says to return every product whose distinct count of cities is equal to the total distinct count of cities in the entire table.

Comment: Hello @Tim Biegeleisen, you know your answer works fine and it will help to create a market basket (for example to analyze prices). Thank you very much for your time and answer, have a great day!